# Google Geocode api always returns ZERO_RESULTS using CURL

Tags: bash, google-maps, curl, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to use CURL in a bash script to get JSON from Google Geocode, but I can't get it to work with --data-urlencode or --data

this will return ZERO_RESULTS:

```
curl -k --data "address=berlin&sensor=false" http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json
```

however this is successful:

```
curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=berlin&sensor=false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to work when I include `-G`.

`curl -G -k --data "address=berlin&sensor=false" http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json`

Comment: perfect! that was the missing piece! :-) I'll accept your answer asap